# SSIS Package - run a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a SSIS package where I pull data from a flat file into SQL. After its ran I have a SP that will ask to insert a value into the columns that are NULL. Can I easily run a SP inside the SSIS package and if so how? Does anyone have a real world example of this? My overall goal is to have a button in a C# Win App to run the SSIS package to pull the data into SQL and then the SP to update the data that just got sucked in.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an Execute SQL task to the SSIS package and you can specify the proc there

I have an example here with a proc that returns XML but the Execute SQL task setup is more or less the same:  [Create XML Files Out Of SQL Server With SSIS And FOR XML Syntax](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/create-xml-files-out-of-sql-server-with-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the execute SQL task to do this. You'll need to define the connection, add the execute statement for the proc and if you have any parameters that will be set from variables, you will need to hook that up as well.